# Why the AudioSource does not play?

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

### This is the setting

[image]

When I `GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play()`, there is no sound, why?

When I check the `play on awake`, the sound is played.  Why?

Comment: That's not enough to answer this. Post picture of your GameObject hierarchy that the Audiosource is attached to. Then post your whole code.

Comment: This is a project under epl license, you can get the code here: https://github.com/tim-hub/TiminesSweeper-3D-/blob/master/Assets/_Scripts/ElementControl.cs

Comment: @Programmer you can get the whole project too, thank you in advance

Comment: Sharing entire projects with people to try to have them track down the problem is not in the spirit of this site. The question you post should be completely self-contained - references to external resources should be supporting, not required. Please, at the very least, provide us the code which is not working for you, perhaps after you've used `Debug.Log()` where necessary to determine whether variables values are what you think they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from `ElementControl.cs`.  You are always destroying the GameObject before the sound even gets to play.

**SOLUTION 1**:

The simple fix for you is to find any code like:

```
Destroy(this.gameObject);
```

in your scene then **replace** it with `Destroy(this.gameObject, 5);`. The **5** will make it wait for **5** seconds before destroying the **GameObject** and the sound may have finished playing by that time. There are about three `Destroy(this.gameObject);` that must be changed. Look for them.

**SOLUTION 2 (Recommended)**:

Change your `void PlayClickAudio()` function to Coroutine then replace anycode that calls it with StartCoroutine. Inside it, play the sound then use audio.isPlaying to wait until the sound is has finished playing. Do other stuff you in the `OnPointerClick` function then you can destroy the GameObject with
`Destroy(this.gameObject);`.Also the original code uses `audio.Play(44100)` which will make it **delay** before playing. Change it to `audio.Play()`.

Here is the new script with solution 2: http://pastebin.com/m1tbVj9k

Comment: Thank you so much. The weired problem is fixed.

Comment: In fact, there is another weired problem too, the `OnParticleCollision` does not work in webgl build. but in pc build, even webplayer build, it works well.

Comment: I've seen that question possibly from you before. I don't know the solution but file a bug to unity and attach your project. If that's a bug, they will fix it. Help->Report a Bug... from the editor.